# Validation is not working if the account got created or not while testing in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

After answers given by Anand and Prophet, I made the changes in the code but now it is not validating the test results whether the account got created or not. Ideally, it should validate whether after giving all the required information account got created or not. I am not sure where it went wrong please help me on the same.

```
package Seleniumtesting;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Selenium {
    ChromeDriver driver;
    String url ="https://login.mailchimp.com/signup/";
    
    public void invokeBrowser() {
        try {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\Selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        driver.get(url);
        String urlFromWebpage = driver.getCurrentUrl();
        if(urlFromWebpage.equals("https://login.mailchimp.com/signup/")) {
            System.out.println("PASS");
        }
        else {
            
            System.out.println("FAIL");
        }
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ex)
          {
              ex.printStackTrace();
          }
        
    }
    public void signup(){
        try {
        WebElement createAccountHeading = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Create an account or ']"));
        if(createAccountHeading.isDisplayed()) {
            System.out.println("PASS");
        }else
            System.out.println("FAIL");
        driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("Testvina12435@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("Testvina1243");
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("Test123@");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        driver.findElement(By.name("marketing_newsletter")).click();
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='create-account']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"create-account\"]")).click();
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        String u = driver.getCurrentUrl();
        System.out.println("URL: "+u);
        /*if(u.equalsIgnoreCase("https://login.mailchimp.com/signup/success/"))
        {
            System.out.println("PASS !! Account created successfully");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("FAIL !! It might have not met the criteria");
        }*/
        driver.close();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ex)
          {
              ex.printStackTrace();
          }
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Selenium mc = new Selenium();
        mc.invokeBrowser();
        mc.signup();
        
    }
    

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This you can use for Sign up:

```
driver.find_element(By. ID, "create-account").click()
```

The caveat is that it gets enabled only when the password criteria is met with, which for mailchimp is at least (as per the website) : 1 lower character, 1 upper character, 1 number, 1 special character, and minimum password length is 8.

I see you used your password as 'Test123' which would not enable the button, as the set criteria is not met. Please check the password rules given just below the password input box of the website.

UPDATE:
Per your latest comment, I am updating here.
I see that when I tested, it redirects to another page where it asks for email confirmation.

```
https://login.mailchimp.com/signup/success/?username=Test1243&userId=168758830&loginId=181489470
```

Now, there is `/success/` in it. And I suppose you are using this page to assert that your act was successful; in which case, I would say that you used `.equals` in your code, which fails it as there is more to the url than you are looking for, so it should not be `.equals`, but it should something be like `.contains` or something like that (I do not know what Java uses, so please search for that equivalent keyword)

UPDATE (Java code edit of @vicky per request)

```
public void signup(){
        try {
        WebElement createAccountHeading = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Create an account or ']"));
        if(createAccountHeading.isDisplayed()) {
            System.out.println("PASS");
        }else
            System.out.println("FAIL");
        driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("Testvina12435@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("Testvina1243");
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("Test123@");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);

        // code edit by @anandgautam

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='onetrust-close-btn-container")).click();
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        driver.findElement(By.name("marketing_newsletter")).click();
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
       
        // end of code edit by @anandgautam
         
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='create-account']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"create-account\"]")).click();
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        String u = driver.getCurrentUrl();
        System.out.println("URL: "+u);
        /*if(u.equalsIgnoreCase("https://login.mailchimp.com/signup/success/"))
        {
            System.out.println("PASS !! Account created successfully");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("FAIL !! It might have not met the criteria");
        }*/
        driver.close();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ex)
          {
              ex.printStackTrace();
          }
        
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick turnaround but when I gave all the details it is not validating whether the account got created or not. I have given if condition where if URL changes then it should give ```Account created successfully`` else ```not``` but I am not getting the validation results on the screen. I have modified the original question

Comment: @Vicky, updated my answer per your comment

Comment: I am extracting the ```url``` value in variable ```u``` but why I am not able to extract it? And also it is not redirecting to the next page once every fields are filled in

Comment: @Vicky, first: Are you able to successfully login? For, the very first time it is asking for the email confirmation (the big `/success/` url that I mentioned in the answer, but the subsequent logins with the same credentials (without email confirmation) gives a different url `https://login.mailchimp.com/signup/post`
Second: Are you getting any error? For me I see that a sleep of 2 is not enough after the click. I baited for 5sec to reach next page. Are you getting any error, or is it just that you are not able to capture the url into var `u` ?

Comment: When I am running the above code by giving 5secs still in the variable ```u``` I am not getting anything in fact this statement is itself not getting executed. What I am thinking is to extract the current URL link into the variable ```u``` and then I will check in this string if it contains ```success``` then my validation will pass otherwise not. But currently I am not getting any value in the variable ```u```

Comment: That's strange. With my limited knowledge on Java, I see no issue with the line you have written in code to fetch current url. Oddly enough, I work with python and when I tried it, it worked with these lines `u = driver.current_url
print(f"URL Now is: {u}")`. I found no issues for I get to print the `u`. One thing I observed is to remove the cookie msg at the bottom of the page, which is obstructing the `Signup` button. I used this: `//div[@id='onetrust-close-btn-container']` and clicked on it to succeed to next page and record the `u`. Are you getting any error?

Comment: Used `//div[@id='onetrust-close-btn-container']` to click on the `X` button of the cookies-footer at the bottom of the page, and I had to click the `X` button before clicking upon `Signup` button.

Comment: Would you please edit the code which I had posted because got confused about what you said? You tested this with python and disabled cookies. Request you to please edit my code for my better understanding

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240916/discussion-between-anand-gautam-and-vicky).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my doubts. It was useful for me to get some ideas from your comment and were able to complete this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your password is missing a special character. The Sign Up button not appearing on that page until you filled all the fields with valid data.
So if you change your password from `Test123` to f.e. `Test123$` you will be able to see, locate and click the Sing Up button with this code:

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='create-account']")).click();
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick turnaround but when I gave all the details it is not validating whether the account got created or not. I have given if condition where if URL changes then it should give Account created successfully`` else not``` but I am not getting the validation results on the screen. I have modified the original question